# Ajax post javascript date as UTC OR server Time

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, datetime, utc

I am trying to post a created date to an ASP.Net MVC controller without the date being modified by the serializer. I am looking for some kind of way to do this on the client.

The date is being constructed as follows:

```
var priceDate = new Date(name.split("-")[1], name.split("-")[0]-1, 1);
```

The date is valid and the problem is the serializer is adding the timezone offset which i don't want. The javascript date should be UTC but this doesn't seem possible.

This problem is expressed in different ways all over the place with all kinds of solutions that just seem way over the top. Is is possible to make a javascript date UTC or devoid of timezone information from the client?

Comment: this seems klugey, but what if it wasnt a date? what if it was **altered** in content and treated as a string?

Comment: Date.UTC() also see Date.getUTCMonth(),yeatr time

Comment: @ArunKillu Date.UTC() returns a number and not a date. My specific issue is i would love to continue sending a js date object rather than switching to some other type. If i switch to another type then there are a ton of solutions. I can use a string or date parts as integers etc.

Comment: @DaveA that is a solution to the big picture issue.. but i am specifically looking for a way to pass a js date object without timezone info.. Which i now understand is not possible.

Comment: I refuse to accept that it's not possible (or at least that I can't force it to be UTC), but it's incredibly frustrating that it should be so hard to do.

Answer (score 1):

There is [toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) function which returns dates in standardized format and always does zero time zone.

Server accepts dates in local zone, so you need to do next `date.ToUniversalTime()`.

So javascrript `date.toISOString()` equals to c# `date.ToUniversalTime()`.

Comment: Yes… but… my date is "2020-11-06 13:11". I _want_ that to be UTC, but my locale settings are UTC-4 and the date object says its value is "Fri Nov 06 2020 13:11:00 GMT-0400 (Atlantic Standard Time)" (itself an abomination -- why can't it at least use ISO format!). So when I do `.toISOString()`, I get the wrong value!